# postgres `in` operator return in query order

Tags: postgresql

I was doing query using `in` operator in `postgres`, something like:

```
select * from items where id in (1,2,3);
```

is there any guarantee that returning entries are in `1,2,3` order?

According to my experiments, the return values are unordered unless I was doing something wrong.

So anyway to get an ordered result? A naive way would be doing n queries and each for only one id, but that involves n traffic between database and have bad performance.

My general requirement would be "batch get using ID and get ordered results"

Comment: As an addition to Juozas' answer - How do you know in advance the disk order of the records - there could have been mulitple `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s. Also, is the `ID` field the PK? Are you searching the entire table or just `SELECT`ing a few records - the result will depend on that also. Also, which records are in which blocks can be a factor! In short, the **only** way to guarantee order is to use an `ORDER BY`! Also, are any records in buffers or are they retrieved from disk?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` doesn't guarantee result ordering. You have to use `ORDER BY` statement:

```
select * from items where id in (1,2,3) order by id;
```